# Using RPi.GPIO with django

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi, gpio, remote-control

I have django project set on my pc and copy of that project on Raspberry pi 3. I deploy changes through pyCharm to raspi. Raspberry is my server where I host my website. I wanted to play with led light through web app. In my app I've imported `import RPI.GPIO as GPIO` but after server run there was **ImportError: No module named 'RPi'**. I've managed to install only gpio on pc (No matching distribution found for RPi), but there is still **ImportError : No module named 'gpio'**. Here is my code in views.py

```
import gpio
LED_PIN = 18
def turnOn(request):
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
    gpio.output(LED_PIN, 1)
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Is there any possibility to use RPi.GPIO in django on pc?

Comment: You cannot get RPi.GPIO on your pc, there are different io connections. However, if you deploy the code to your raspberry pi and run you can use RPi.GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

RPi.GPIO is Raspberry-specific and you really cannot use it on your computer - it even has no GPIO ports. You should deploy your code to RPi and use it there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. With help of wiringPi and subprocess I could execute command.

```
def turnOn(request):
subprocess.call(['gpio', '-g', 'mode', '3', 'out'])
subprocess.call(['gpio', '-g', 'write', '3', '1'])
return HttpResponse('')
```